# How can I join two data extensions and count the values ​of a column using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to join a Data Extension with another and count a specific value on Column, but don't work.

```
SET @SearchBase = 'Base1'
    
SET @IDBase = Lookup(@SearchBase, 'id', 'id', ID)
SET @BaseFull = Lookup('TbFull', 'ID', 'ID', @IDBase)
      
SET @rowsGCU = LookupOrderedRows('TbFull',1000000,"Status Desc","Status", Field(@BaseFull ,'Control Group'))
SET @rowCountGCU = rowCount(@rowsGCU)
```

I want this code to relate the two bases and return the complete base with the records that were related by grouping the values ​​by the status field

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data from the `Base1` and `TbFull` DEs as well as the desired output in your email.

Comment: Also, there's no "joining" in the AMPscript lookup functions only row-sets and loops.  The lookups can certainly be nested in loops.